# Open Trip Planner - Error no graph registered with routerID

Tags: java, transit, general-transit-feed-specification, opentripplanner

I am new to using OTP. I followed the basic tutorials instructions to start OTP, with own data, as well as with the data indicated within the tutorial. I get it to run the grizzly server, but opening local host shows no results and in my Windows command line the ERROR message "no graph registered with router ID" occurs. Further when I want to switch to the analysis window in OTP another error message occurs saying something like "Not possible, out of bounding box". My folder structure is

> D:\Program\Portland\otp

for the jar-file and the inpput (gtfs.zip &osm.pbf) data is stored under

> D:\Program\Portland\otp\graphs

my command to launch otp reads as following:

```
D:\Program\Portland\otp> java -Xmx1G -jar otp-0.19.0-shaded.jar --build --inMemory --analyst
```

I checked all solutions offered found via google and the result kept the same. Anyone an idea what myproblem could be?

Answer (score 2):

I used this program in two steps. The first build the graph and save it :

```
D:\Program\Portland\otp> java -Xmx1G -jar otp-0.19.0-shaded.jar --build D:\Program\Portland\otp\graphs
```

if the last folder 'graphs' refers to the folder containing the files gtfs.zip & osm.pbf

Then the second step to run the server :

```
D:\Program\Portland\otp> java -Xmx1G -jar otp-0.19.0-shaded.jar --server --basePath D:\Program\Portland\otp\ --router graphs --analyst
```